# Where are tokens stored?

Tags: tokens, ico

I am trying to create my own token and confused a bit. As I understood from the documentation all information about adresses and tokens amount is stored inside contract (ERC20 - `mapping(address => uint256) balanceOf`). But somebody says to me that token could be sold using services like myetherwallet by uploading wallet. That is weird.

So my questions are following:

1. Am I right that once contract implemented ad uploaded ALL information about token transfers, sells and buys stored in the contract itself?
2. How understand statement like "myetherwaller supports ...coin"? Does it means that I can sell tokens outside contract?
3. How to make my token world-wide-available? Or just need to provide a way to exchange ETH -> Token?
4. Am I right that token name could be any, even duplicate existing one, but shortname (ERC20 `symbol`) must be unique?

Comment: Tokens are just counters that live inside a contract. The ERC20 standard (https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) specifies certain functions that let APIs access different tokens in the same way. Transferring x tokens from person A to B translates to computing `balances[A] -= x; balances[B] += x;` How you choose to give out tokens is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right that once contract implemented ad uploaded ALL information
>   about token transfers, sells and buys stored in the contract itself?

Yes, you're correct, the transfer of tokens are stored in the mapping. It's like the excel sheet where the address is stored in one column and tokens are stored in next column. While transferring tokens, the address is added to that sheet in address column with respective tokens.

> How understand statement like "myetherwaller supports ...coin"? Does it means that I can sell tokens outside contract?

Selling token means your transferring tokens to the address and this mapping will be stored in the mapping function.

> How to make my token world-wide-available? Or just need to provide a way to exchange ETH -> Token?

You have to compile and deploy the contract in the main live ethereum network. After that other can interact with contract using contract address.

> Am I right that token name could be any, even duplicate existing one, but shortname (ERC20 symbol) must be unique?

No, It's not necessary that Token name and Token Symbol needs to be unique.
You can create as many token contracts with same name and symbol. You can differentiate only based on contract address.